# retrieverecord not assigning the value to the value from the web api?

Tags: javascript, async-await, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I'm creating a var where I want to assign it to a var that I get from another entity

```
function SubmitAction(executionContext) {
var lookupItem = formContext.getAttribute("alfa_member").getValue()[0].id;
var theTotalMembersTravling = formContext.getAttribute("alfa_numberofdependent").getValue();
var remainFlightCredit;

debugger;
Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveRecord("contact",lookupItem, "?$select=new_remainstravelcredit").then(
     function employessPackage(result) {
        var new_remainstravelcredit = result["new_remainstravelcredit"];
        if(new_remainstravelcredit !== null){
        if(new_remainstravelcredit > 0)
        {
            remainFlightCredit = new_remainstravelcredit;
            console.log(remainFlightCredit+" This not inside any if condition");

                    var newRemain = (parseInt(remainFlightCredit)) - (parseInt(theTotalMembersTravling));
                    console.log(newRemain+ " This in the remain if condition");
                    var entity = {};
                    entity.new_remainstravelcredit = newRemain.toString();
                    Xrm.WebApi.online.updateRecord("contact",lookupItem, entity).then(
                    function success(result) {
                        var updatedEntityId = result.id;
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
                    }
                );
        } if(new_remainstravelcredit <= 0)
        {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("You have exceeds the travel credit");
            console.log(remainFlightCredit);

        } 
    }
    },
    function(error) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
    }
);



  console.log(remainFlightCredit);
}
```

So as result in this line

```
 remainFlightCredit = new_remainstravelcredit;
 console.log(remainFlightCredit+" This not inside any if condition");
```

Which inside the webapi call I'm able to get the value but outside in the main function at the end when I write

```
      console.log(remainFlightCredit);
```

I'm unable to get the value `remainFlightCredit`, do you have any suggestions to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior, as this is a promise call (asynchronous) the code outside the main api call will execute before the success callback function `employessPackage`.

So `remainFlightCredit` value get assigned after the last `console.log` line in your code.

You can place a breakpoint to debug and see it in action.